# what molecule would have molar entropy $R \ln 2$ at $0K$?

Tags: statistical-mechanics

I was browsing my friends old notes and I came across the following problem that I am not sure if it's correct.

> Q. Prove that the molar entropy of **CO** of $0K$ would be $R \ln 2$.

Here, it is considered that the thermodynamic probability of $N$ molecules of **CO** is $$w = \frac{N!}{\left(N\over 2\right)!\left(N\over 2\right)!} $$ 
I was wondering what this **CO** molecule might be and why would it have thermodynamic probability as above in $0K$. Can any one explain that?

**P.S.** I am not sure if the problem was stated correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CO is carbon monoxide. If you lay down these molecules in a lattice, each can have two orientations, almost equal in energy. Because of this, even at 0 K, carbon monoxide has [residual entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual_entropy) because it's not a perfect crystal.

There are $2^N$ microstates available. The number of ways to get the most probable situation - half the molecules with one orientation, half with the other - is given by the factorial formula you state.